# Items in GridBagLayout does not properly align

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to align 3 items in a GridBagLayout, 2 of the items being on top and 1 item at bottom. Both Items should be the same Size. I have tried to achieve this with BorderLayout and GridBagLayout but no luck.

[image]

This is my attempt with GridBagLayout as you can see they are not properly aligned. This is what I tried to do.

```
Add first item
Set the x to 1
Add second item
Set the y to 1
Add the last item
```

I was hoping this would work because It doesn't make sense to me why this would not work, Here is the code for it.

```
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    JTextField oldPkg = new JTextField();
    container.add(oldPkg, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    JTextField newPkg = new JTextField();
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    JTextField apkPath = new JTextField();
    container.add(apkPath, gbc);
```

The result I want to achieve is

[image]

I have achieved it with FlowLayout but it doesn't resign packed when the frame is resized, and the bottom bar is a bit big.

How can I achieve this with GridBagLayout or any other layout so it remains the same on size changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to set back and try a different approach.  Maybe starting with and piece of paper, where you can draw the layout and plot out the constraints.

This will lead you to understanding that `apkPath` needs to start at `x` of `0` and "span" two columns.

Currently `apkPath` is using the same `x` position as `newPkg`, you need to change it before using it again.

```
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.gridx = 0;
JTextField apkPath = new JTextField();
container.add(apkPath, gbc);
```

Okay, but now it's the same size as `oldPkg`, we need to tell `GridBagLayout` we want to span multiple columns

```
gbc.gridy = 1;
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridwidth = 2;
JTextField apkPath = new JTextField();
container.add(apkPath, gbc);
```

should now allow the textfield to flow over both columns

I might suggest having a look at [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Looks like I didn't have enough coffee tonight. How ever this works but there is no padding between the top and bottom panels. http://prntscr.com/ljcii0

Comment: @SamzSakerz Now would be a good time to hit the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#insets) to see what other properties are available to you ;)

Comment: `gbc.insets` does the job for any future comers to this post.

Answer (score -2):

Slightly off topic: 
Might I just suggest not bothering with 90% of the inbuilt layouts and just going with MigLayout.

There is a MigLayout core jar, and MigLayout swing jar. (Don't take the MigLayout SWT jar by mistake, and also don't use the SWT versions in the import statements).

I guess the licence is liberal. But, you can check whether it fits your needs.

http://www.miglayout.com/

(Just a happy user. Not affiliated)

This does a lot in just a few lines:

```
public class LayoutAnswer extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                LayoutAnswer window = new LayoutAnswer();

                window.init();
                window.pack();

                window.setVisible(true);
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });

    }

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel( new MigLayout("insets 10","[300::, grow][400::, grow]","[100:150:200][100:150:200]") );
    private JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("One");
    private JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel("Two");
    private JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel("Three");
    public void init() {
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        panel.add(lbl1, "");
        panel.add(lbl2, "wrap");
        panel.add(lbl3, "span 2");
    }
}
```

[image: Sample image. Resizes nicely.]